# Making a quiz game using python but only the else statements work

Tags: python, if-statement

So I'm somewhat new to coding but I think I know basic things but I've spent a while trying different things but nothing has worked it might be something obvious that I've just over looked but I'm just not sure.
There isn't and actual error but what happens is even when I put the right answer in it only prints out the else statement. Any and all help is appreciated, thank you.

````
#at the end you go back through and see the ones you got wrong and it tells you the correct answer
import random

inccorrect = ["Good try but its wrong.", "Not quite the answer, you gave it a good shot though."]
correct = ["That is correct.", "Correct."]

def MQ1():
    print("What does 2 + 2 =")
    input("Enter the answer:")
    if input == float(4):
        print(random.choice(correct))
    else:
        print(random.choice(inccorrect))

def MQ2():
    print("Lets make these questions harder.")
    print("What does 4³ =")
    input("Enter the answer:")
    if input == "64":
        print(random.choice(correct))
    else:
        print(random.choice(inccorrect))

def MQ3():
    print("Lets see how far you can get!")
    print("What does 6*10⁴ = ")
    input("Enter the answer:")
    if input == "60000":
        print(random.choice(correct))
    else:
        print(random.choice(inccorrect))

#scoreboards keeps count of how many Qs you have gotten right or wrong
#need to check the answers
#need to count right and wrong answers and show above the next answer

#to avoid just printing out everything at once need to check if each question has been answered
def main():
    MQ1()
    MQ2()
    MQ3()
main()```
````

Comment: You need to store the output of your `input ("Enter the answer:")` in a variable and then test the contents of that variable in your `if` statement (or alternatively you could do `if input("Enter the answer:") == "64"` etc). Also note that `input` returns a string, so you would need to compare it with `"4"` rather than `float(4)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def MQ1():
    print("What does 2 + 2 =")
    answer = input("Enter the answer:") # STORE the input from user
    if float(answer) == float(4):
        print(random.choice(correct))
    else:
        print(random.choice(inccorrect))
```

You need to store the input that the user is entering.

Comment: Still trying to compare a string and a float.

Comment: Fixed it.. Thanks